# Linearity of convergent series fails with infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is not a question per se but more a paradox I'd like to better understand.

*[Basic Analysis](https://www.jirka.org/ra/realanal.pdf)* by Lebl gives the following linearity property of convergent series:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty (x_n +y_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n $$

Yet, consider the following series (the triangular number divided by $ N^2 $):

$$ \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{n}{N^2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{N(N+1)}{N^2}$$

Taking the limit as $ N \rightarrow \infty $, the series converges to $1/2$. Yet each term in the series (i.e. $1/N, 2/N....n/N^2)$ converges to $ 0 $. So the latter, by the linearity property, would seem to imply the whole series should converge to $ 0 $.

Comment: It does not imply that. What you've written down is not a series but a sequence of series, and it shows that taking pointwise limits does not commute with taking infinite sums in general. But linearity is a simpler property (it only involves two series, or more generally finitely many series, at a time) and it is not violated here.